# How to use a nested if else statements in a for loop in c

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, nested

I'm having issues with my for statement. I'm trying to have a nested if else statement inside and I'm using pointers. I've tried everything and I've looked all over the internet. I've placed comments beside the lines with errors but if you see something else that's wrong please let me know. Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

void getinput(double*xptr, int*nptr)
{
int flag;
    do
    {
      flag = TRUE;
      printf("What is the value of x and the number of terms:");
      scanf("%lf %i", xptr, nptr);
      if (*nptr <= 0)
      {
        printf("The number of terms must be positive\n");
        flag = FALSE;
      }
    }
    while(flag == FALSE);
}

double sinHyper(double *xptr, int *nptr) {
    int i;
    double sum;
    double ti;
    i = 0;
    ti = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < *nptr; i = i+1)// I'm getting a Warning: comparioson between pointer and integer
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            sum = xptr;
        } else {
            ti = 2*i+1;
            ti = ti*2*i;
            ti = (xptr*xptr)/ti;// I'm getting a error: invalid operands to binary * (have 'double*' and 'double*')
            sum = ti*sum;
        }
    }
    return (sum);
}

void main() {
   int n;
   double x;
   double sinhx;
   getinput(&x, &n);
   sinhx = sinHyper(&x, &n);
   printf("For an x of %.0f with %i terms the sinh(x) is %f", x, n, sinhx);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to dereference your pointers in several places.

The fact that this line compiles

```
sum = xptr;
```

should not mislead you: C lets you convert a pointer to a number with only a warning, while in most cases this is an error. This line should be

```
sum = *xptr;
```

It does not let you multiply pointers, so the expression where you square your pointer is an error:

```
(xptr*xptr)
```

You should either dereference the pointer twice, i.e. write

```
((*xptr)*(*xptr))
```

or make a separate variable for the current value of `*xptr` and use it instead:

```
const double x = *xptr;
ti = (x*x)/ti;
```

**Note:** This exercise should be purely theoretical, because `sinHyper` does not change `*xptr` or `*nptr`. Therefore, you should pass them as values, not as pointers:

```
double sinHyper(const double x, const int n) {
    ...
}
...
sinhx = sinHyper(x, n);
```

Comment: I changed everything and now I'm getting a warning: operations on i may be undefined          on the for line

Comment: @Cplan Modified version of the code works perfectly for me ([demo](https://ideone.com/NvB9U7)). I modified `i = i + 1` to a more common `i++`.

Comment: Ok it's working now and it turns out that I had made a mistake in my calculations that's why I wasn't getting the values I wanted but thank you so much man you helped me out big time!!!!!!!

Comment: @Cplan You are welcome! If this answers your question, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the gray checkmark next to it. This would let other site visitors know that your problem has been solved, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.